# Next.js: Error: Failed to collect page data for /

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, peerjs

I have added `peerjs` to a Next.js app, and the following two lines, like this. If I remove those two lines, app works.

```js
// index.tsx

import { Peer } from 'peerjs'

export default function Home() {
    const peer = new Peer('pick-an-id-jwrn')
```

and`yarn build` raise this error, why? I have successfully installed package.

```
    at Object.982 (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/serverless-chat/.next/server/pages/index.js:50:41)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/serverless-chat/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /
    at /Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/serverless-chat/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:949:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

Comment: Try dynamically importing `peerjs` inside a `useEffect` instead, e.g. `const { Peer } = await import('peerjs')`.